# Cannot Retrieve Custom Control Pattern After Registration

Tags: c#, .net, c++, wpf, ui-automation

I'm using the automation API to create custom control patterns. Now that I've created my custom patterns, I don't know how to retrieve the existence of my new patterns. I've tried to use AutomationPattern.LookupById() in the following code:

```
PatternWrapper pattern = new PatternWrapper();
int res = pattern.RegisterRotatePattern();
AutomationPattern rotatePattern = AutomationPattern.LookupById(res);

Assert.IsTrue(new List<String (Enum.GetNames(typeof(PatternInterface))).Contains("CustomRotatePattern"));
```

Is there another way to retrieve the pattern or perhaps I need to derive a custom AutomationPeer??

I do get a pattern id after registering the pattern but still have no idea how to retrieve the pattern. Any ideas would be very helpful!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does LookupById succeed, or does it return null? Regardless of whether it succeeds or fails, the Assert after it will never succeed: PatternInterface is an enum that WPF uses to list the patterns that it knows about at the time that it was developed. It does not (and could not - because enums are fixed at compile time) update to contain newly registered patterns.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure if *implementing* custom patterns is possible in WPF. WPF has its own layer for supporting UIAutomation - the Peer classes - and while UIAutomation has since added support for custom patterns, it doesn't look like WPF has been updated so that its Peer infrastructure also has that support. Or at least I can't see a way for a WPF AutomationPeer to return a pattern other than the fixed set (PatternInterface enum) that WPF was built with.

Comment: @BrendanMcK LookupById does succeed and return the id 5000.

Comment: @BrendanMcK What about if implemented in c++? I have the custom pattern implemented in c++ with a managed wrapper (PatternWrapper). Would there be a way to then access the pattern itself?? Thanks for your response, some discussion is always helpful.

Comment: You can definitely do it in C++ or C#; the custom id gets passed as the patternId parameter to IRawElementPRoviderSimple::GetPatternProvider(). What I'm not sure about is whether the PatternInterface enum that WPF uses in its AutomationPeer.GetPattern() method is just the same numeric value, but as an enum type, or if the PatternInterface enum is a parallel set of values unrelated to the IDs that UIA uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I did some research (a lot of research) and noticed that I did not implement the server-side provider for my unmanaged code. By implementing the server-side provider, I should be able to retrieve a pointer to my custom control.

Hopefully that does it, I'm in middle of implementing it at the moment. Thanks for your help BrendanMcK, get me thinking with that last comment of yours there!